# How do I include shortcuts for the gnome setting program and wine apps in dmenu?

Tags: gnome3, i3, desktop-shortcuts, dmenu

I would like to use `dmenu` as my launcher instead of the Gnome3-overlay that is displayed after hitting the super-key. From the Gnome3-overlay, I am able to launch both apps, gnome settings, and wine programs. In `dmenu`, I am so far only able to launch apps, and I can't seem to find the gnome settings program or any of my wine apps.

When I tried other launcher, such as `synapse`, they were able to find both the settings and wine apps, just like with the gnome-overlay. I prefer `dmenu` because it is the fastest and most aesthetically pleasing launcher I have come across. Is there a way to include shortcuts to the gnome setting program and my wine apps in `dmenu`?

I am using Antegros Linux with Gnome 3.22 and dmenu 0.1  (specifically, the dmenu2 package from the AUR).

---

#### Update

For the gnome settings app, I figured out the name is `gnome-control-center` although it is called "Settings" in the Gnome3-overlay window. Adding the `-z` flag to dmenu helped by enabling fuzzy matching.

I also found out that the keyboard subsection of the settings menu is launched via `gnome-control-center keyboard`, which is a little bothersome to type every time since it does not autocomplete.

It seems like `dmenu` will find everything that I put on my `$PATH`, but I am not super keen on including all the desktop shortcuts there. Other launchers such as `p-menu` includes everything on `$PATH` and all the `.desktop` files on the system, which is the preferred behavior to me. `p-menu` does only seem to launch within a terminal, rather than as a popup (the latter being faster for me), so for the time being, I am using `albert`, which works great. I would still be interested in `dmenu` or a similar launcher, if they include `.desktop`-files.

Answer (score 0):

When you install application via Wine it will create desktop files in 2 places:

- `~/.wine/drive_c/users/username/Desktop` -- for shortcuts on desktop;
- `~/.local/share/applications/wine/Programs` -- for all shortcuts in main menu.

It probably will be enough to include only first one (where only launchers located, without all these Uninstall/Visit our site/etc shortcuts) to the `PATH`. And if you don't want to include them for all applications you could setup separate path only for `dmenu` and launch it like:

```
$ PATH="$HOME/.wine/drive_c/users/username/Desktop:$PATH" dmenu_run
```

Answer (score 0):

[i3-dmenu-desktop](https://github.com/i3/i3/blob/next/i3-dmenu-desktop) is a perl script uses search for desktop file and pipes it into dmenu to launch desktop files

dmenu is really just a program to dynamically generate menu's, when used as a launch it is in reality just piping the user selection into the shell in order to launch, i kinda abuse that tidbit in [dfuse](https://github.com/fuseteam/dfuse) by creating several script around dmenu itself, some of them based off of the dmenu_run shell script